# Multiple Solution Layout for ASP.NET Web Portal?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

At work, we've developed a custom ASP.NET Web Portal (That's very similar to iGoogle). We have "Apps" (self-contained, large web forms) and "Modules" (similar to Google Gadgets).

Currently, we use a single-solution model. Right now, we have:

- 3 core projects
- 60 application projects
- 80 module projects

To reduce copy and pasting between projects, we're going to factor out common functionality (Data Access, Business Logic) into separate projects. I'd also like to introduce Unit Tests, which is going to increase the number of projects even more.

We've already reached the point where Visual Studio is choking on the number of projects. We generally only load the 3 core projects and then whatever app's/module's project we're working on.

Would a different solution structure help us out? Our number of projects is only going to increase.

In general, an app or module only references the 3 core projects. Soon, apps/modules may start referencing the Data Access/Business Logic projects. But in general, apps and modules do not make references between themselves.

So to recap, what is the best practice for solution structure when there are MANY projects that use a small number of core projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have developed similar ASP.NET web portals based on strong modular principles. Tax we pay is lots of Visual Studio projects.
There is a single master solution with all modules, web-sites, unit-tests and so on but this solution is usually infeasible to work with on day-by-day basis on computers with small amount of RAM (<= 4 GB).

We have common infrastructure code (~ 10 projects) and business module projects. A single business module is composed of all projects dealing with some aspect of business requirements, e.g. Orders, Customer management, Distribution... The business module typically has:

- ASP.NET web application project (which becomes a sub-web of the Shell module web-site),
- domain model assembly (class library with no dependencies) + interface assembly,
- OR/M adapter for domain model (we use Entity Framework and NHibernate),
- front-end assembly with presenters, controllers, view models, ...,
- back-end assembly with module business services and DTOs + interface assembly,
- unit test assemblies,
- other assemblies (like Silverlight components, MSQM DTOs, etc.).

We use SLNTools Filter (http://slntools.codeplex.com/) to filter out single business module VS solutions from the master solution. So we have solutions OrdersModule.sln, CustomersModule.sln etc. Each such solution has common infrastructure projects (~10) and the module projects (~10-15). SLNTools Filter automatically includes all dependent projects so it's very easy to create a new filtered solution.